# How to send any file format in Android?

Tags: java, android

I need help how to send any file format in Android. In this my file format is .jpg. If i have .pdf or .png, how can I do this?

This is my code:

```
case R.id.share:

            Intent picMessageIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            picMessageIntent.setType("image/*");                    
            File downloadedPic =  new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("SIPRO"),value1+".jpg");

            picMessageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(downloadedPic));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(picMessageIntent, "Send your picture using:"));

            return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you wish to send files as email attachments. The code that you have pasted should work for any attachment type.

Have you tried attaching different format files? If yes, then what are the issues that you are facing?

The only change I can suggest is instead of setType(image/*) try to use setType(text/plain) or setType(text/html). Make sure that the file that you want to send is available on the device and you pass the correct path of it.